# Unable to Retrieve data from the postgress database using Php?

Tags: php, postgresql, server, record

I have created a Php file, which fetches the data from the Postgres Database, but when I run the file it doesn't displays the contents (records) which are present in the database table.

I ran this using both Apache server and Python SimpleHTTPServer also.

I restarted the Postgres server too.

[image: This is the Output which I get]

Below is the code of that file:

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            webpage
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            INFORMATION OF DATABASE
        </h1>
        <?php 
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "myappuser"; 
$pass = "password"; 
$db = "myapp"; 
echo "\n test";
$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM app1_snippet"; 
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['phone_no']. " " . $row['status'];
    echo "\n";
}
pg_close($con); 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may help to `print_r(con);` right after `pg_connect()` and then `print_r(rs);` after `pg_query()` so it becomes more evident whether you have actually connected and performed the query rather than your table is empty.

Comment: The echo command before you even connect seems not to work so it is not a postgres error. You're getting a 500, turn on debugging and see what's the error.

Comment: @anton samsonov i have done that but its not showing anything

Comment: As Jakub recommends, inspect your webserver's error log — PHP dumps all significant messages there.

Answer (score 0):

Ya figured out how to do.
below is the Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>WELCOME</head>
<body  style="background-color:#E4E5E7">
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 {
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: #f1f1c1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<?php
$url= 'http://yoururltypehere.com';
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => array(
                   'name: '.$_GET['name'],
                 ),
    'method'  => 'GET',
  ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$output = file_get_contents($url, false,$context);

$arr = json_decode($output,true);


?>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th> 
    <th>PHONE_NO</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </tr>

    <br>
        <?php
    for($x=0;$x<count($arr);$x++)
    {
                ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $arr[$x]['id']; ?>

    <td><?php echo $arr[$x]['name']; ?>
    <td><?php echo $arr[$x]['ph_no']; ?>
    <td><?php echo $arr[$x]['stats']; ?>
    </tr>
         <?php

               }
                 ?>

    <br>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```